# constructor initializer lists vs default initializer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list

In the following example below (c++11):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(int x): v1{x} {}

    int v1 = 0;
    int v2 {v1};

    void print() const {
        std::cout<<"v1:"<<v1<<" v2:"<<v2<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    const auto bar1 = foo();
    bar1.print();  // prints v1:0 v2:0
    const auto bar2 = foo(42);
    bar2.print();  // prints v1:42 v2:42
}
```

I understand about the rule of `v1`. `bar1.v1` is default initialized, and `bar2.v1` is intialized by the constructor, with default initializer ignored.

What I am curious about is `v2`, even though `bar2.v2` is default initialized, it will use the `v1` that is initialized by the constructor. My question is: is this the correct behavior according to c++ standard? I cannot seem to find a good source for this.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Anything not specified in the member init list falls back to the in-class initializer.

Comment: Auzn: Did my answer answer your question or do you still have doubts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether default initialized or initialized in the member initializer list, the member variables are initialized in the order of declaration, so yes, this is exactly how it should be.

[`class.base.init`/13](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13):

13 In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:

- (13.1)
  First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class ([intro.object]), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
- (13.2)
  Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
- (13.3) **Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).**
- (13.4)
  Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
  [Note 6: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. — end note]